# how to access a variable from another Roblox Studio script

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a game on Roblox Studio and in one script I need to get the given record in a variable that is in another script. Please help me solve the problem.

i tried to do like this

```
if workspace.OxranukTrue.OxranukTrue.BarierNumber == 0 then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_G.BarierNumber` to define your variable in the defining script and to reference it.

In script 1:

```
_G.BarierNumber = 0
```

In script 2:

```
if _G.BarierNumber == 0 then
```